# I cannot add with 'git add' the file named P3_x_code

Tags: git, github

i get the error fatal: pathspec when trying to add the file. I also used "P3_\X_\code". How else can I write this?

Comment: What is the exact command you're running, where in the directory are you running it from, and where in the directory is the file?

Comment: Im placed in the correct file which is P3_x_code and trying to do git add before commiting.I'm doing all this in the Visual code terminal. So I type git add "P3_\X_\code" and I get the above mentioned error

Comment: It would be helpful if you fully copied your command, and any error message into your question so people can see exactly what you see. 
I assume you have initiated the repository. Have you successfully added other files?

Comment: Yes,I added other files but with a simple name like index.html and not a nme with underscores in it. Command and error:emilia@MacBook-Pro-de-emilia P3-X-code % git add P3-X-code
fatal: pathspec 'P3-X-code' did not match any files
emilia@MacBook-Pro-de-emilia P3-X-code %

Comment: how deep are the folders? is the "code" a file or a folder?

Comment: So as you can see I'm correctly positioned in the file I want to commit with git but when I do git add it says fatal: pathspec 'P3-X-code' did not match any files emilia@MacBook-Pro-de-emilia P3-X-code.Hmm,am I writing the file inccorectly?Code is in the file name. It is a folder which contains index.html,style.css,images and so on.

Comment: Try this - type `git add "P3-X-cod` and then press tab. If you're in the right directory, this should autocomplete the name of the file. Is it possible you're missing the file extension from your command?

Comment: I try this when I position myself in the corrct folder but with the command git add it doesnt autocomplete the name of the folder

Comment: It looks like you're already *in* a folder named `P3-X-Code` (note the hyphens, not underscores). Does this also have a sub-folder or file with a similar name, or did you just mean to run `git add .` to add all files at the current folder and in sub-folders?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.